# Is there a belt you can use to bypass the ac compressor on a 2006 Honda accord 2.4 4cyl

Tags: honda, accord, serpentine-belt

Is there a belt you can use to bypass the ac compressor on a 2006 Honda accord 2.4 4cyl

Answer (score 3):

Using the following routing, you can bypass the A/C compressor:

[image]

The belt [needs to be ~55.875" long](https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/Discussion-d589_ds681764). Since it is a 7-rib belt, you'd need something like a [Dayco 5070563](http://www.daycoproducts.com/part?part_type%3D20%26length_search%3D56%26num_ribs%3D7%26part_number%3D5070563) (which might be a tad long, but should work). (NOTE: I have no affiliation with Dayco ... it's just their website is the only one I could find which did lookup by size). This Dayco belt is 56.3" long. If from the site I linked, 55.875" belt length was *very tight* and a "bear to install", this length should make it easier and still work fine.

Answer (score 2):

There may well be but it depends on two things:

1) a valid path for the belt including the adjuster

2) a belt of the correct length

You can measure the path with a piece of string and match that length - do check the tooth spacing and that the adjuster is fully retracted when you measure...

Comment: @Jupiter not needed for my vehicle (Jaguar) because a belt from a Renault works... Perhaps you should comment directly to the O P.

Answer (score 0):

A dayco 5060555 or a bando 6pk1410 will work ,they are only 6 rib but by not running the ac a 6 rib will work ,we have done this a number of times with no problems